# Select blocks for apparently no reason after being run three times in a row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have a relatively simple script to load some csv data to a MariaDB server, that first loads the file using LOAD DATA INFILE (without issues), and then does some light filtering on the data before normalizing it for insert into another table for use.

When there's a single file to load, all works correctly, but for one reason or another, it may be necessary to load several of them in a row, and that's when things get weird: the first two files are quickly loaded, processed and their data stored, but when it comes time to select data from the temporary table for insertion, the SELECT apparently blocks at "sending data" (from what SHOW PROCESSLIST shows).

Originally, I had been using

```
INSERT INTO final_table ... SELECT ... from temp_table 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

but as it stopped loading, I replaced it with a SELECT first and then tried to INSERT each row, but again it blocks on the third time.

I have tried to create a new connection before working on each file, but still the problem persists.

What could be happening, or what could I try to narrow down the problem?

Edit: here's the code, sorry for not posting it before. I removed try blocks and output statements (that I had been using to show progress).
The SELECT query in the $sql_select variable is the one that's causing trouble, but only after it runs twice without any problems.
It should have been simple.

Edited again: cleaned up the clean up.

```php
            $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csvfile' into table carga_toa_basica
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES (
                    provedor, numero_ordem, nome_produto, tipo_atividade, estado,
                    @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, 
                    inicio, fim,
                    @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @24,
                    razao_nao_executado_1, razao_nao_executado_2, razao_nao_executado_3, ordem_servico,
                    @29, @30, @31, @32, @33, @34, @35, @36, @37, @38, @39, @40, @41, 
                    data,
                    @43, @44, @45, @46, @47, @48,
                    mudanca_endereco,
                    @50, @51, @52, @53, @54, @55, @56, @57, @58, @59, @60, @61, @62, @63, @64, @65,
                    @66, @67, @68, @69, @70, @71, @72, @73, @74, @75, @76, @77, @78, @79, @80, @81,
                    @82, @83, @84, @85, @86, @87, @88, @89, @90, @91, @92, @93, @94, @95, @96, @97,
                    @98, @99, @100, @101, @102, @103, @104, @105, @106, @107, @108, @109, @110, @111,
                    @112, @113, @114, @115, @116, @117, @118, @119, @120, @121, @122, @123, @124, @125,
                    @126, @127, @128, @129, @130,
                    troca_tecnologia)
            ";
            $db->query($sql);

            $sql_insert = "
                insert into toa_basica(provedor_id, numero_ordem, nome_produto_id, tipo_atividade_id, estado_id,
                    inicio, fim, razao_nao_executado_id_1, razao_nao_executado_id_2, razao_nao_executado_id_3,
                    ordem_servico, data, mudanca_endereco, troca_tecnologia, atividade_normalizada_id)
                    values (:provedor_id, :numero_ordem, :nome_produto_id, :tipo_atividade_id, :estado_id,
                    nullif(:inicio, ''), nullif(:fim, ''), :razao_nao_executado_id_1, :razao_nao_executado_id_2, :razao_nao_executado_id_3,
                    :ordem_servico, :data, :mudanca_endereco, :troca_tecnologia, :atividade_normalizada_id)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inicio=values(inicio), fim=values(fim)";
                
            $sql_select = "
                select p.id as provedor_id, numero_ordem, n.id as nome_produto_id, a.id as tipo_atividade_id, e.id as estado_id, 
                    inicio, fim, 
                    r1.id as razao_nao_executado_id_1, r2.id as razao_nao_executado_id_2, r3.id as razao_nao_executado_id_3, ordem_servico,
                    STR_TO_DATE(data, '%Y/%m/%d') as data, 
                    (case when c.mudanca_endereco = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as mudanca_endereco, 
                    (case when c.troca_tecnologia = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as troca_tecnologia,
                    ta.id as atividade_normalizada_id
                from carga_toa_basica c
                join toa_provedores p on p.provedor=c.provedor
                join toa_nome_produtos n on n.nome_produto=c.nome_produto
                join toa_tipo_atividades a on a.tipo_atividade=c.tipo_atividade
                join toa_estados e on e.estado=c.estado
                join toa_razoes_nao_executado r1 on r1.razao_nao_executado=c.razao_nao_executado_1
                join toa_razoes_nao_executado r2 on r2.razao_nao_executado=c.razao_nao_executado_2
                join toa_razoes_nao_executado r3 on r3.razao_nao_executado=c.razao_nao_executado_3
                join toa_atividades_normalizadas ta on ta.tipo_atividade_id=a.id and 
                        ta.mudanca_endereco=(case when c.mudanca_endereco = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) and 
                        ta.troca_tecnologia=(case when c.troca_tecnologia = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)              
            ";

                $stmt_insert = $db->prepare($sql_insert);
                $stmt_select = $db->prepare($sql_select);
                $stmt_select->execute();
                $rows = $stmt_select->fetchAll();
                
                foreach($rows as $num => $row) {
                    $stmt_insere->execute($row);
                }
```

Edit 2: I gave up on trying to solve the problem and used an ugly work around of updating the temporary table field by field and then transfering the data to the main table.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help

Comment: do you use a single temporary table for all files or each file is using its own?

Comment: That's quite a robust code. Did you try a single INSERT...SELECT instead of selecting and looping over the resultset though?

Comment: I did. It was the first thing I tried, but when it blocked on the third file being processed, I first assumed it had been due to the unique index and tried looping over the resultset, thinking it might be some particular row causing the problem, and originally put a print_r to find when it would stop .

Comment: How much data?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I gave up, but about 300-500 rows with less than 64 characters  (at most, before normalizing the data), default values for a mariadb install in Debian 10, and the most boring tables possible. The main one only 15 varchar columns, and any others just a id and varchar. I gave up and found another solution.